# Verify Ibatis Procedures Called in Java

Tags: java, ibatis, legacy-code

I am working on legacy code which has a number of defunct database calls in it's ibatis mapping files. I am hoping to connect the ibatis mappings back to the java class files - or more accurately find which mappings do not get called by the java.

The purpose is to remove the calls from the mapping file and the procedures from the database.

Right now I can see no other way than to parse the mapping file, pick up each procedure's java id and then do a search in the java class files for where it might be called.

Has someone had to do this before? Or can someone see a better way to tackling this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by parsing the mapping files? you mean you open it and get all the ids by copy pasting them to a text file then searching them one by one in eclipse's workspace by Ctrl+ H?

Comment: Well I was intending on automating the process so it can be re-run after future releases. So I would have a script that read the mapping file - when it hit a procedure (<procedure id=".." parameterMap="..">) it would explode the string on id etc to pick out the procedure ID. I can then grep the java source directory for it excluding the mapping file, if it is not found print out the parameterId and the procedure called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

Write a small java program that:

1. Searches all the `iBatis` configuration files
2. Gets all the ids and persists them in a file (or in a collection)
3. Searches all the .java files in the persistence level (that start with the persistence level package names)
4. Whenever it finds the id used in any persistence class removes it (from the collection/file)
5. At the end it will print out (into a file) all the ids not found and
   their configuration file names

It's very easy to write a program like this, it will just take a 15 minutes max and will save you days.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Myers - I had been thinking of doing two steps as one and unnecessarily complicating the process. This will simplify it and make it more readable.

Comment: I pulled together a java program to recursively locate the ibatis files, extract the procedures and then recursively check the java files for the procedures and removing them from the list if they are found. The only thing I do wonder is if it is really a good pattern - it is rather data intensive but without either going to scripting and using grep or something internal to java to search files I do not see a better option.